# In VBA, is a one-dimensional array a row, a column, or any?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

When working with a one dimensinal array in VBA, should we think of it as a row, a column or it doesn't matter?

Comment: The short answer is in vba it does not matter.  If you are going to try and assign the array to a worksheet range then it does as it is a horizontal array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. VBA exists outside of Excel, e.g. in PowerPoint or in Word. There you have no rows or columns, but arrays exist.